# Can't understand these:free immediately after malloc;close file immediately after open

Tags: c, memory, curses

I am reading some source code about an old management tool for bank teller written by c using curses,here are some codes I can't understand:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int h1, h2;
    char *m1, *m2;
    char fname[100];

    sprintf(fname, "%s/welcome.txt", getenv("xxDIR"));

    m1 = malloc(1);
    free(m1);

    h1 = open(fname, 0);
    if (h1>0) 
        close(h1);
    else 
        fprintf(stderr,"Open first  file : %s \n", strerror(errno));

    func1(argc, argv);

    h2 = open(fname, 0);
    if (h2>0) 
        close(h1);
    else 
        fprintf(stderr,"Open second file : %s \n", strerror(errno));

    if (h1!=h2) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"File Open/Close Check: h1=%d, h2=%d\n", h1, h2);
    }

    m2 = malloc(1);
    free(m2);

    if (m1!=m2) 
    {
        printf("Mem  Alloc/Free Check: %ld\n", (long)(m2-m1));
    }       

    exit(0);
}
```

Like I asked why it free immediately after malloc and close file immediately after open? And func1 is here:

```
func1(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char trad_code[5];
    int xx1();
    int xx2();
    int xx3();
    int xx4();
    int xx5();
    int prt_translate(char *fmt, char *data);

    signal( SIGINT, SIG_IGN );

    scr_open();
    clear();
    refresh();

    while ( scr_kbhit() ) scr_getch();

    screen_set_function ( screen_FUNCID_CONFIRM, xx1 );
    screen_set_function ( screen_FUNCID_SETDATA, xx2 );
    screen_set_function ( screen_FUNCID_GETDATA, xx3 );
    screen_set_function ( screen_FUNCID_FLDIN,   xx4 );
    screen_set_function ( screen_FUNCID_FLDOUT,  xx5 );
    prt_set_transfunction ( prt_translate );

    if (sysinit()!=0)   
        goto sysexit;

    Show_Title();
    refresh();

    if (Show_Welcome())
        goto sysexit;

    strcpy(trad_code, "0000");
    do_menu( "0000", trad_code, xxx );

    syskill();

sysexit:

    clear();
    refresh();
    while ( scr_kbhit() ) scr_getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears that this code just does some sanity checks to understand whether the environment behaves in an expected way. In particular, it checks whether allocating 1 byte of heap memory, freeing it and allocating another byte will yield reuse the byte in memory (`m1 == m2`), and similarly, whether opening a file, closing it again and opening another one will reuse the file handle (`h1 == h2`).

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the `func1` call in the middle. I think LPs is half-right - I think it's not about hacking (because hackers could just free their memory and close their files), but to check whether `func1` is leaking any heap memory and/or any file handles. `func1` is supposed to clean up its stuff and not leave anything dangling, I guess. **EDIT**: I'll transform this into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in my comment, it appears to me that this is a check to see whether `func1` is leaking memory or file handles.

Essentially, the code checks whether allocating memory before and after the call will give back the same memory address, as well as opening a file before and after the call will give back the same file handle.

If `func1` calls `malloc` but forgets to `free` the memory again, or it opens a file and doesn't close it again, the values of `m1` and `m2` or `h1` and `h2`, respecitively, will be different.

However, this is not a portable approach. It might work on one specific platform, but there is no guarantee that the heap and the file handles will be reused like that on other platforms - they may return different values before and after `func1` even if nothing was leaked.

Comment: Good answer. It clarify all things.